# Не стесняться присутствием ― это правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи

Бывшие коллеги, ***не стесняясь его присутствием***, выразительно крутили пальцем у виска, а потом и вовсе ополчились на него (А. Денисов "Магические врата", **2006 год**).

**СТЕСНЯТЬСЯ,** 1. к Стесниться. 2. **(кого-чего).** Испытывать чувство неловкости, застенчивости, смущения. Он не стесняется сказать грубость. С. взрослых, детей, девочек, мальчиков. С. **из-за** своей одежды. С. из-за дефектов речи. С. перед девушками.

Какой должен быть падеж, родительный или творительный?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В "Словаре управления" Д.Э. Розенталя вариант с творительным падежом помечен как устаревший.

> СТЕСНЯТЬСЯ — 1. (испытывать чувство неловкости, застенчивости,
>   смущения) кого (вин.п.; устар.) / чего / кем-чем (устар.). *Сначала он
>   стеснялся Екатерины Михайловны* (Остр.); *Володя... ужасно стеснялся
>   отца и мать* (Шуг.); [Главный врач]  *любил отпускать двусмысленные
>   шутки, не стесняясь  присутствием женщин* (Сим.).

Comment: Спасибо. А это соответствует действительности, Т.п. не употребляется в современных текстах?

Comment: Употребляется, но, похоже, всё реже. Я думаю, такое употребление выглядит уместно, если подразумевается высокий стиль (или под старину). Иначе немного режет глаз.

Comment: А стесняться из-за его присутствия - тоже как-то странно выглядит.

Comment: Впрочем, именно "стесняться присутствием", по-другому и вообразить сложно. Тогда можно рассматривать как фразеологизм. Нормально звучит "стесняться его присутствия".

Comment: Да, не стесняясь его присутствия - это нормально смотрится. А Т.п. может еще в ироническом смысле использоваться, как это бывает с устаревшими выражениями.

Answer (score 3):

*А это соответствует действительности, Т. п. не употребляется в современных текстах?*
Вот что нашлось в [Нацкорпусе](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%F1%F2%E5%F1%ED%FF%F2%FC%F1%FF&gramm1=&sem1=&flags1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%EF%F0%E8%F1%F3%F2%F1%F2%E2%E8%E5&gramm2=&sem2=&flags2=&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=1&lex3=&gramm3=&sem3=&flags3=&p=0).

Но дело в общем-то знает, ― **не стесняясь присутствием сотрудника**, охарактеризовал Фархадов. [Семен Данилюк. Бизнес-класс (2003)]

Говорили главным образом, **не стесняясь присутствием гостей**, о делах служебных, иными словами, о производимых в их ведомстве арестах соратников Генриха Ягоды ― предшественника Ежова на его посту. [Борис Ефимов. Десять десятилетий (2000)]

Тут же сел на лавочку и, **не стесняясь присутствием великого коллеги**, заглянул внутрь тетради с целью очередной ревизии сочиненного. [Владимир Войнович. Замысел (1999)]

Нечасто, конечно, но выражение употребляется и сегодня.
С середины XIX века до тридцатых годов прошлого века эта форма употреблялась чаще других.

Comment: Спасибо. А как Вы думаете, в этих примерах нейтральная стилистика?